# Generating a file reference from a substring F#

Tags: string, f#, substring

I'm having trouble generating a file reference in F# from a substring.

I have an input file and I want to create a uniquely identifiable output file from a truncation of the input file name.

My code is as follows:-

```
    let sillyString = @"BookingsAberdeen.csv";;


    let cutString = sillyString.Substring(8);;

    let outputFile = "@" + cutString;;

    outputFile;;
```

But it is not coming out quite right. I'm getting "@Aberdeen.csv", but I need it to be @"Aberdeen.csv".

Can anyone advise as to the correct code to use for outputFile?

Many thanks,

Simon

EDIT: Removed unneccesary test line from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is the verbatim string modifier.

> If preceded by the @ symbol, the literal is a verbatim string. This
>   means that any escape sequences are ignored, except that two quotation
>   mark characters are interpreted as one quotation mark character. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx)

It stops F# from interpreting e.g. `"c:\test.txt"` as `"c:[TAB]est.txt"`.  Once the string has been interpreted correctly, you don't need to worry about @-ing it - just remove `"@" +` from the fourth line.

Comment: Cheers, that's very helpful. I was misunderstanding the "@" operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape initial and closing quotes:

```
let outputFile = "@\"" + sillyString + "\"";
```

Comment: Thought it would be something simple. Amazing how hard it is when you don't know these things. Thank you.

Comment: This actually gives me "@"Aberdeen.csv"" Which is not quite what I was hoping for :).